# Why aero_busy.ani cursor is not animated with SetSystemCursor win32 API?

Tags: winforms, api, winapi, c#-4.0, win32-process

> [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>           static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);
>
> [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>           static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);

```
 IntPtr hcur = LoadCursorFromFile("C:\\windows\\cursors\\aero_busy.ani");
 SetSystemCursor(hcur, OCR_NORMAL);
```

I am using the above API for the load busy cursor.The busy cursor get load but it is not animated.

Can anyone help me why it is not animated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use `IDC_WAIT` and respect the user's preferences?

Comment: Indeed, what's wrong with `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;`?

Comment: Same problem  : IntPtr hcur = LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, IDC_WAIT);
            SetSystemCursor(hcur, OCR_NORMAL);

Comment: I wants to change the system cursor.

Comment: Users likely won't want that though, it is a singularly unfriendly thing to do. At least you've learnt not to do this with `LoadCusorFromFile` since that is very brittle.

Comment: I am doing some operation on IE browser from my exe.

Comment: Users aren't going to like your program forcing its cursor choices onto the other programs they use

Comment: Does the IE plugin API not have a way to indicate business?